# Audio will not unload in FlashBuilder with FullScreen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I've been working with a problem unloading audio that has been playing from Youtube. I made a simple video player that I include below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="init()"  >   
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
[Bindable] public var videoAddress:String 
private static const YOUTUBE_EMBED_URL:String = "http://www.youtube.com/v/";            
[Bindable] public var videoUrl:String;                                  
private function init():void {
    //The following two line are needed to unload the youtube audio
    SoundMixer.stopAll()
    swfLoader.unloadAndStop(true)
    videoUrl = YOUTUBE_EMBED_URL+videoAddress;
}           

    ]]>
</mx:Script>    
<mx:SWFLoader id="swfLoader" source="{videoUrl}"  width="640"   height="387" />

</mx:Canvas>
```

I discovered that the following two lines were needed to prevent the audio from playing:

```
    SoundMixer.stopAll()
    swfLoader.unloadAndStop(true)
```

All was going well until I entered a part of my project where I use full screen:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Immediately, ALL of the audio clips, that had previously been played and stopped, started to play at the same time!
I assume that I have a garbage collection issue but have no idea how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need add an Event listener to restop the sound when the Fullscreen mode is active

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.FULLSCREEN, onFullScreen);


private function onFullScreen(e:Event):void{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    swfLoader.unloadAndStop(true);
}
```